# How to Save Add meta box woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

In there i want to add custom meta box in my order woocommerce. i've already create it but in there i have problem whenever i try to save its doesnt change here my code :

```html
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes' );

function add_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'woocommerce-order-my-custom', 
        __( 'Order Driver' ), 
        'order_my_custom', 
        'shop_order', 
        'side', 
        'default' 
    );
}
function order_my_custom()
{ 
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "no_password";
  $dbname = "testtable";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='drivers'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "<select style='width:100%;' >";
    echo "<option> --- Select ---</option>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=".$row['ID'].">".$row['post_title']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

}
```

what should i do now ? have someone give me solution so my code can work like what i want ?

when i use :

```
echo "<option".($selected=='')?'':'selected'." value=".$row['ID'].">".$row['post_title']."</option>";
```

[image: error]

if i only use :

```
echo "<option value=".$row['ID'].">".$row['post_title']."</option>";
```

[image: should]

now  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the code to save the selected driver's id in order meta while saving the order after selecting driver.

I've not tested the code but hope it helps.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes' );

function add_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'woocommerce-order-my-custom', 
        __( 'Order Driver' ), 
        'order_my_custom', 
        'shop_order', 
        'side', 
        'default' 
    );
}
function order_my_custom()
{ 
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  $order_id  =$post->ID;
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "no_password";
  $dbname = "testtable";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='drivers'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ob_start();?>
   <select name='order_driver' style='width:100%;' >
    <option value=""> --- Select ---</option>
    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $order_driver = get_post_meta($order_id,'order_driver',true);
    ?>
    <option <?php echo ($row['ID']==$order_driver)?'selected':''?> value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>"><?php echo $row['post_title']?></option>

  <?php  } ?>
   </select>
  <?php } else {?>
   <option value="">0 Results</option>
    <?php }
    echo ob_get_clean();
$conn->close();

} 

function save_drivers_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    /*
     * Make sure we are updating post meta only for shop orders
     */
    if ( "shop_order" != $post_type ) return;

    // - Update the post's order_driver value if it's set.

    if ( isset( $_POST['order_driver'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'order_driver', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['order_driver'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_drivers_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: oke, thats help me. but in there it was give a litle trouble when i use :
`echo "<option".($selected=='')?'':'selected'." value=".$row['ID'].">".$row['post_title']."</option>";`

when i use that code my select want to show any data.

have u solution for me ?

Comment: sorry i'm having trouble understanding :( . could you var_dump($row)inside the while loop and show what's comming in $row?

and screenshot of the order page that's displaying the meta box.

Comment: oke its work want to show the data but its have a problem with the data where i selected its doesnt same with the data in datatable

Comment: What do you want to save and what is it saving currently?

Comment: now its must select the data with name adam account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128919/discussion-between-yamu-and-adam-projo).

Comment: ok, then try to update as below:
replace 
global $post; 


by 
global $product; $post = $product->id;

I've updated the answer, if that sitll does not work then we can continue the discussion in chat. Comment is getting longer :P